# How can I give variation to animation curve in Unity? (Raw mocap data)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, interpolation

I am trying to give subtle variation of animation to Unity avatar. Currently, avatar moves exactly to what animation keyframe instructs. Animation I am using is Raw Mocap Data for Mecanim by Unity(https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/animations/raw-mocap-data-for-mecanim-5330).
I also noticed that Unity interpolates between keys in keyframe to offer "Smooth" movement.
However, I would like to programmatically change this smoothing(interpolating) in given time interval.

I tried changing the "Curve" in animation inspector tab but it didn't work.

Also, I tried manually changing the interpolation curve in Animation window curves (curve option between Dopesheet and Curves button). However, it looks like I cannot change them because its Read-only file. 
How may I change it?

Eventually, I want to make avatar move with certain variation, just like humans do.

Thank you for sharing your time!

Comment: transforms are generalliy additive, you can always add variation by adding some low frequency (i.e. perlin) noise

Comment: @zambari Thanks for the advice! I should try perlin noise

Comment: @zambari If i wish to add noise to animation, which value of animation should I consider?